# how to host wcf service on hosting server?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf

I have created WCF service. And I hosted my website on a server with a domain name like [www] domain name [com]. I want to consume WCF service. How can I host or deploy or attach WCF service on [www] domain name [com] or server?

Comment: Does the server have IIS?  If so simply deploy it to the server and create an application in IIS that points to the service.  That's step #1.  If it doesn't work then you'll need to provide more details.

Comment: yes, server have IIS. after login, their are options, among those options iis setting and another dedicatied iis application pool.

Comment: Here's a small tutorial than might be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766(v=vs.110).aspx